# Get data from list of EditTexts in a recycler view to a list?

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-edittext, android-adapter, android-textwatcher

```
I am having an EditText in a TTextInputLayout as a Row_item for my recycler view, On the click of a button I am incrementing the count value in that recycler view and adding the edit text views in the app. After having as many views as I want, I am putting some data in those EditTexts and After all this I press save button and all the data from EditTexts should save in a list. I tried the textwatcher Property in xamarin.android but not able to perform that.
```

In my activity I also tried

```
var view = addChildRecyclerView.FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                var holder = view as fragmentRecyclerViewAdapterViewHolder;
                if (holder != null)
                {
                    holder.childname.FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.enterChildNameTextView);
                   
                    childlisttosend.Add(holder.childname.EditText.Text);
```

But sometimes I get holder as a null and some valus are missed to be put in the list.
I tried textchange property but it puts every single alphabet in the list, like

```
for index 1 it is "m"
for index 2 it is "ma"
for index 3 it is "man"
for index 4 it is "mani"
for index 5 it is "manis"
for index 6 it is "manish"
```

It is of no use. Please sugggest a solution.
adapter is

```
namespace assessment1_part2_v2.Fragment
{
    public class addFamilyFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        public TextInputLayout fathername, mothername, address;
        public MaterialButton addchild, savebutton;
        public ArrayAdapter adapter;
        public ListView listview;
        public familyData familydata = new familyData();
        public List<childData> childrenList = new List<childData>();
        public editTextAdapter EditTextAdapter;
        public event EventHandler<DataSenderClass> famaDataSender;
        public RecyclerView enterChildRecyclerView;
        public List<string> addChildDummyData = new List<string>();
        public TextInputLayout enterChildEditTExt;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.addfam_layout, container, false);
            connectingViews(view);
            buttonClicks();
            return view;
        }

        public class DataSenderClass : EventArgs
        {
            public familyData data { get; set; }
        }

        private void buttonClicks()
        {
            addchild.Click += Addchild_Click;
            savebutton.Click += Savebutton_Click;
        }

        private void Savebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //father, mother and address
            familydata.fathername = fathername.EditText.Text;
            familydata.mothername = mothername.EditText.Text;
            familydata.location = address.EditText.Text;
            familydata.children = new List<childData>();
            List<childData> list = new List<childData>();
            List<string> dummyCheck = new List<string>();
             for (int i = 0; i <= addChildDummyData.Count; i++)
            {
                var viewholder = enterChildRecyclerView.FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                
                var holder = viewholder as editTextAdapterViewHolder;
               // holder.addChildEditTExt;
                if(holder != null)
                {
                    holder.addChildEditTExt.FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.enterChildEditTExt);
                    dummyCheck.Add(holder.addChildEditTExt.EditText.Text);
                }

            }
            var x = dummyCheck;
            addChildDummyData.Clear();
            famaDataSender?.Invoke(this, new DataSenderClass { data = familydata });
            this.Dismiss();
        }

        private void Addchild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (addChildDummyData.Count == 0)
            {
                addChildDummyData.Add("");
                EditTextAdapter = new editTextAdapter(addChildDummyData);
                enterChildRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity));
                enterChildRecyclerView.SetAdapter(EditTextAdapter);
                int x = enterChildRecyclerView.ChildCount;
            }
            else
            {
                addChildDummyData.Add("");
                EditTextAdapter.NotifyItemInserted(addChildDummyData.Count - 1);
                int x = enterChildRecyclerView.ChildCount;
            }
        }

        private void connectingViews(View view)
        {
            fathername = view.FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.enterFatherNameEditText);
            mothername = view.FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.enterMotherNameEditText);
            address = view.FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.enterAddressEditText);
            addchild = view.FindViewById<MaterialButton>(Resource.Id.addChildButton);
            savebutton = view.FindViewById<MaterialButton>(Resource.Id.saveButton);
            enterChildRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.enterChildRecyclerView);
            //listview = (ListView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.enterChildRecyclerView);
        }
    }
}                   `
```

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't see the code of `editTextAdapter`.

But you can refer to my code ,my `RecyclerView` has an `Edittext` in each item and we can get data from the input list.

I put `TextWatcher` in my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`(`PhotoViewHolder.cs`).

PhotoViewHolder.cs

```
public class PhotoViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
    public TextView Caption { get; private set; }
    public CheckBox MyCheckBox { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public EditText MyEditText { get; set; }

     public MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher;


    public Button imAddBefore { get; private set; }
    public Button imAddAfter { get; private set; }

    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener, MyTextWatcher myWatcher  ) : base(itemView)
    {
        //Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView);
        Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        MyCheckBox = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.myCheckBox);

        DeleteButton = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.deleteBtn);

        MyEditText = itemView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.mEditText);
        this.myTextWatcher = myWatcher;
         // add TextWatcher here
        MyEditText.AddTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);


       // other code

    }


    public class MyTextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
    {
        int position;

        public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
        {
        }

        public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        { //mInput  is a field in my item model
            PhotoAlbumAdapter.mPhotoAlbum[position].mInput = s.ToString();
        }

        public void updatePosition(int position)
        {
            this.position = position;
        }

    }
}
```

My `RecyclerView.Adapter` is `PhotoAlbumAdapter.cs`

PhotoAlbumAdapter.cs

```
  public class PhotoAlbumAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter
  {
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

    public static List<Photo> mPhotoAlbum = new List<Photo>();

    public static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<Photo> branchesList)
    {
        adapter = this;
        mPhotoAlbum = branchesList;
    }


    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.PhotoCardView, parent, false);

        PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, OnClick, new PhotoViewHolder.MyTextWatcher());
       
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;

        Photo item=   mPhotoAlbum[position];

        vh.Caption.Text = item.Caption;
        
        // here we call function `updatePosition` in our TextWatcher class
        vh.myTextWatcher.updatePosition(vh.AdapterPosition);

        vh.MyEditText.Text = item.mInput;

        // other code
    }


    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mPhotoAlbum.Count; }
    }

    // Raise an event when the item-click takes place:
    void OnClick(int position)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)
            ItemClick(this, position);
    }
}
```

In my activity, we can get the data from the recycleview like this:

```
  List<Photo> items= new List<Photo>();

  mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(items);
  mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The result is:

```
  for (int i=0;i< items.Count;i++) {
    Photo temp = items[i];
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "The "+i +" result is: "+" Caption= " + temp.Caption + "<---> input = " + temp.mInput);

   }
```